# How to remove the Nuxt loading page in PWA mode

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps

I just created a PWA using NUXTjs + the PWA configuration.

I've uploaded it to firebase and it works fine on my phones browser.

But when I save it to the home screen. When I run the app, I get the Nuxt loading screen before entering the app. Is there a way to remove this or customise it to my use?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Would you share your `manifest.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change `icon.png` existed in `static` folder.

Or you can change defaults with following doc:
https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/modules/icon.html#options